# How to fix Ubuntu 16.04 crash

Tags: 16.04, steam, crash

Every once in a while my computer freezes up and crashes, and shows this on the display (forgive me for the bubbles on the OTHER display, that's a different separate computer):

[image]

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on a 2016 Razer Blade Stealth (4k touchscreen display, no graphics card, intel i7 processor).

It crashes when I sometimes play a game with steam, or even am just browsing the web using chrome, or writing code in terminal with vim.

Any help on how to solve is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You shoul probably try to scan your memory with memtest86+. It is included in ubuntu installation DVD. Current version does not support the efi mode, so You should try to boot Ubuntu in legacy mode to get memtest grub option available.

Comment: I've tried to run memtest, but everytime i do it freezes up. I upgraded to ubuntu 17.10 and have the same issue still